# How to change Swap Drive in /etc/fstab on OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse, fstab

I installed 4 linux distributions on my drive, 4 partitions one after the other. Part way through installation I deleted the swap partition because it was in the wrong place. I recreated the swap at the end of the drive.

For Archcraft this was fine, I started up one of the working linux installations, edited /etc/fstab on the Archcraft installation, changed the swap guid and next boot was good to go.

openSUSE was another story. I did the same, updated /etc/fstab on the openSUSE partition from a working linux installation and this did not work. Next boot I got this message,

```
A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/f8fe8f1b-093e-47bb-bf87-725d6e119836 (12s / 1min 30s)
```

This would not boot which makes sense, but that's not the guid I added to /etc/fstab for the swap drive.

Here is the /etc/fstab from the openSUSE installation, guid starting with f8fe above vs cfb4 below,

```
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /                       btrfs  defaults                      0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /var                    btrfs  subvol=/@/var                 0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /usr/local              btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local           0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /root                   btrfs  subvol=/@/root                0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /opt                    btrfs  subvol=/@/opt                 0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /home                   btrfs  subvol=/@/home                0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /boot/grub2/i386-pc     btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/i386-pc  0  0
UUID=954B-B690                             /boot/efi               vfat   utf8                          0  2
UUID=cfb4647b-9b75-4cfc-a354-733575ae9174  swap                    swap   defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=9s                      0  0
```

This is definitely the right /etc/fstab because this is the only installation where I used btrfs. Also the result of this,

```
cat /media/petermc/166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14/var/log/boot.log | grep /dev/disk
```

Gives me this. Boot log with this error and /etc/fstab are the same drive,

```
A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/f8fe8f1b-093e-47bb-bf87-725d6e119836 (12s / 1min 30s)
```

Here is the result of blkid

```
sdb                                                                        
├─sdb1 vfat   NO_LABEL 954B-B690                             378.2M    26% /boot/efi
├─sdb2 ext4            a136db60-b89d-4fcb-88d2-4ead35d93914  151.9G    17% /media/petermc/a136db60-b89d-4fcb-88d2-4ead35d93914
├─sdb3 btrfs           166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  249.2G     2% /media/petermc/166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14
├─sdb4 swap            cfb4647b-9b75-4cfc-a354-733575ae9174                [SWAP]
├─sdb5 ext4            ac901ab9-87ab-4902-a1f7-e70e93bdf518  204.3G     4% /
└─sdb6 ext4            5d9bc00d-a45c-4cd3-bd9c-1f81857ed101  208.8G     3% /media/petermc/5d9bc00d-a45c-4cd3-bd9c-1f81857ed101
```

I tripple checked I was editing the right /etc/fstab. I tried two things. Change the guid in the /etc/fstab and you can see this above. The second was commenting out the line in /etc/fstab.

```
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /                       btrfs  defaults                      0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /var                    btrfs  subvol=/@/var                 0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /usr/local              btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local           0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /root                   btrfs  subvol=/@/root                0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /opt                    btrfs  subvol=/@/opt                 0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /home                   btrfs  subvol=/@/home                0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  0  0
UUID=166ab229-50bb-446a-9498-3b1ee5523c14  /boot/grub2/i386-pc     btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/i386-pc  0  0
UUID=954B-B690                             /boot/efi               vfat   utf8                          0  2
#UUID=cfb4647b-9b75-4cfc-a354-733575ae9174  swap                    swap   defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=9s                      0  0
```

Neither worked. Is openSUSE loading the swap details from elsewhere and how can I reset it? This completely goes against my understanding of the use and purpose of the /etc/fstab file.

Comment: Add the contents of the `/etc/fstab` for OpenSUSE to the question along with the UIDs of the disks which can be retrieved via `lsblk -f`.

Comment: I think you might need to update grub in order to change the UUID of the swap partition. Check `yast bootloader` for the kernel parameters, you likely have a `resume=/dev/disk-by/...` entry there which might need an update.

Comment: Eblock, add this as the answer. It worked